# Multi-part identifier could not be bound SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to do a simple copy of a table from one database to another where a condition is true.  However, I am getting a "multi-part identifier could not be bound".  My spelling is correct as Intellisense is prompting me through correctly.

Example:

```
USE database2
SELECT * INTO database2.dbo.Table1
FROM database1.dbo.Table1
WHERE database1.dbo.Table1.Column1 = database2.dbo.Table2.Column2
```

SQL will complain that the "database2.dbo.table2.Column2" multi-part identifier cannot be bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this instance, intellisense doesn't make the statement legitemate.

I think you are wanting to do something along these lines:

```
SELECT d1.* INTO database2.dbo.Table1 
FROM database1.dbo.Table1 d1
INNER JOIN database2.dbo.Table2 d2
WHERE d1.Column1 = d2.Column2
```